# Limit character length and add hyphen in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to make a code is entered and a - is added before the last two digits and is six characters long without the hyphen , the codes that I attach work, but separately, it doesn't matter if I try to join them to make it work or call them independent the result is always the same:

the code length is limited to 5, and the hyphen ends in the last character

how can I solve that?

```
function check(code) {
        
        var r = code.value.replace('.', '');
        vlr = r.replace('-', '');
        body = r.slice(0, -2);
        dv = vlr.slice(-2).toUpperCase();
        code.value = body + '-' + dv
        if ( body.length < 4 ||body.length > 6) {
            patente.setCustomValidity("incorrect");
            return false;
        }
        code.setCustomValidity('');
    }



    $(document).ready(function () {
        var code = 6;
            $('#code').keydown( function(e){
            if ($(this).val().length >= code) { 
                $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, code));
            }
        });
        
        
        $('#code').keyup( function(e){
            if ($(this).val().length >= code) { 
                $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, code));
            }
        });
        
        
        });
```

Comment: You are using jquery as well, correct?

Comment: yes, i use jquery ..

Comment: Ok. I will add a jquery tag